# Django model form with field not existing in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using Django 3.2

I have a model like this:

```
class BannedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ban_info")
    reason = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=BANN_REASON_CHOICES)
    banned_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Date on which ban expires'))
```

I want to create a form that instead of asking user to select a date, simply asks the user to select the Ban duration. The form will then calculate the expiration_date in the `clean()` method.

```
BAN_DURATION_3_DAYS=3
# ...

BAN_DURATION_CHOICES = (

    (BAN_DURATION_3_DAYS, _('3 Days')),
   # ...

)


class BannedUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BannedUser
        fields = ['reason', 'ban_till']
```

The form field `ban_till` is a PositiveInteger that maps to the number of days. The intention is then to calculate the expiry_date from today by offsetting the integer amount.

I suppose one way would be to:

- create a dynamic field `ban_till`
- add field `expiry_date` to the form field list (but somehow prevent it from being rendered)
- in the form's `clean()` method calculate the expiry_date and update that field

How to create a form to display field that does not exist in Model?

My solution:

```
class BannedUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['ban_till'] = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.ChoiceField())
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = BannedUser
        fields = ['reason']
```

Is this the correct way to do this - or are there any gotchas I need to be aware of?

Comment: you mean you want to hide this in form in UI `expiry_date` thats it?

Comment: I want to display only the `reason` and the `ban_till` choices. Once the user selects those two then in the `clean()` method, I will populate the model fields correctly, before saving the model.